# MUI "Master Detail" disable functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, master-detail

Regarding the [Master Detail](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/group-pivot/#master-detail) feature of [MUI](https://mui.com/); when [exporting to CSV from a Data Grid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/#csv-export) while implementing Master Detail the CSV export functionality stops working (understandably). Technically it works but only exports the first row (in my case). I looked around for a disable functionality of the master detail like there is for [disableRowGrouping](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/group-pivot/#disable-the-row-grouping) prop for groups but was not able to find one. Does this functionality exist and if not, do you have any suggestions on how I can turn on and off the Master Detail prop?

I did try conditionally adding the master detail feature to the `DataGridPro` component using state and a ternary statement like `{!!someState ? getDetailPanelContent={({ row }) => <div>Row ID: {row.id}</div>}: false}` however was not able to do so. I'm not sure if you can have conditional component props. Is this when a [spread operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) is used? If so, maybe someone can give an example of how to implement these two together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you might call a rookie mistake. I was applying a ternary operation to the entire property and not just the value of the property.

Incorrect: `{!!someState ? getDetailPanelContent={({ row }) => <div>Row ID: {row.id}</div>}: false}`

Correct: `{getDetailPanelContent= {!!someState ? {({ row }) => <div>Row ID: {row.id}</div>}: false} : null}`.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
// Custom State to manage disabling of panelContent
const [disablePanelContent, setDisablePanelContent] = useState(true);

// queryResponse is data being put into the DataGrid; '[0]' being the first row returned
// columnToTrigger is the column from the queryResponse that I want to trigger either showing or disabling the panelContent
if (!!queryResponse[0].columnToTrigger {
    setDisablePanelContent(false);
  } else {
    setDisablePanelContent(true);
  }

<  DataGridPro
// ...
getDetailPanelContent = {!!disablePanelContent ? null : getDetailPanelContent} // Answer
// ... 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below didn't work for me to conditionally render the expand icons for the master detail, so I wanted to share my working solution:

```js
// MUI: Always memoize the function provided to getDetailPanelContent and getDetailPanelHeight.
 const getDetailPanelContent = useCallback((params: GridRowParams<any>) => <CustomDetailPanel params={params} rowExpansion={rowExpansion}/>, []);

// Inside of the datagrid - conditionally render based on rowExpansion
{...(_.isEmpty(rowExpansion) ? {} : { getDetailPanelContent:getDetailPanelContent })}
```